# Where is Maven Installed on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, maven

I installed maven on my Ubuntu machine with the command `sudo apt-get install maven`

Now I need to know where it is installed in order to configure the same in IntelliJ..

Comment: This quetion is for http://askubuntu.com

Comment: note that repository is at /home/$username/.m2

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Ubuntu, which is a Debian derivative, follows a very precise structure when installing packages.  In other words, all software installed through the packaging tools, such as apt-get or synaptic, will put the stuff in the same locations.  If you become familiar with these locations, you'll always know where to find your stuff.

As a short cut, you can always open a tool like synaptic, find the installed package, and inspect the "properties".  Under properties, you'll see a list of all installed files.  Again, you can expect these to always follow the Debian/Ubuntu conventions; these are highly ordered Linux distributions.  IN short, binaries will be in /usr/bin, or some other location on your path ( try 'echo $PATH' on the command line to see the possible locations ).  Configuration is always in a subdirectory of /etc.  And the "home" is typically in /usr/lib or /usr/share.

For instance, according to http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-install-maven-in-ubuntu/, maven is installed like:

> The Apt-get installation will install
>   all the required files in the
>   following folder structure
>
> /usr/bin/mvn
>
> /usr/share/maven2/
>
> /etc/maven2
>
> P.S The Maven configuration is store
>   in /etc/maven2

Note, it's not just apt-get that will do this, it's any .deb package installer.

Comment: Kleu, I followed the same link but overlooked this information..Thanks for pointing me..the `/usr/share/maven2` worked

Answer (score 55):

```
$ mvn --version
```

and look for Maven home: in the output
, mine is: `Maven home: /usr/share/maven`

Comment: This is very helpful. This is required when we intend to set Maven home. But this is only for maven, not working for other tools like java, git etc.

Comment: The problem here is when unfortunately maven is still not in the path variable.

Comment: This will work not out well if the path is not set yet

Answer (score 50):

Depends on what you are looking for. If you are looking for the executable :

```
$ whereis mvn
```

If you are looking for the libs and repo :

```
$ locate maven
```

With the locate command, you could also pipe it to grep to find a particular library, i.e.

```
$ locate maven | grep 'jetty'
```

HTH

Comment: how can i get a list by pausing it so that the list doesn't quickly scroll down?

Comment: @codechimp just pipe the output to `more` like this : `locate maven | more`. Use the `space` key to scroll down the list.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bash script for newer Maven copy and paste it...

```
# @author Yucca Nel

#!/bin/sh

#This installs maven2 & a default JDK 
sudo apt-get install maven2;

#Makes the /usr/lib/mvn in case...
sudo mkdir -p /usr/lib/mvn;

#Clean out /tmp...
sudo rm -rf /tmp/*;
cd /tmp;

#Update this line to reflect newer versions of maven
wget http://mirrors.powertech.no/www.apache.org/dist//maven/binaries/apache-maven-3.0.3-bin.tar.gz;
tar -xvf ./*gz;

#Move it to where it to logical location
sudo mv /tmp/apache-maven-3.* /usr/lib/mvn/;

#Link the new Maven to the bin... (update for higher/newer version)...
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/mvn/apache-maven-3.0.3/bin/mvn /usr/bin/mvn;

#test
mvn -version;

exit 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add that .m2 folder a lot of people say it is in your home folder. It is right. But if use maven from ready to go IDE like Spring STS then your .m2 folder  is placed in root folder

To access root folder you need to switch to super user account

`sudo su`

Go to root folder

`cd root/`

You will find it by

`cd -all`

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu 11.10 doesn't have maven3 in repo.

Follow below step to install maven3 on ubuntu 11.10

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:natecarlson/maven3
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install maven3
```

Open terminal: mvn3 -v

if you want mvn as a binary then execute below script:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/mvn3 /usr/bin/mvn
```

I hope this will help you.

Thanks,
Rajam

Answer (score 0):

[image: Ubuntu Show Hidden Files]

In Ubuntu -> Home -> left most *Options* button -> select *Show hidden files*

Now `.m2` folder will be visible

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sdkman than it should be installed in:

```
home/(username)/.sdkman/candidates/maven/(version)
```

you could also use `current` instead of `(version)` if you're switching versions often.