# .m2 , settings.xml in Ubuntu

Tags: java, linux, maven, ubuntu, pom.xml

In the windows environment you will have .m2 folder in C:\Users\user_name location and you will copy your settings.xml file to it in order to setup your proxy settings and nexus repository locations and etc.

So What I have to done on Ubuntu environment to get similar setup after installing maven on it.

Answer (score 48):

As per [Where is Maven Installed on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5312350/where-is-maven-installed-on-ubuntu) it will first create your settings.xml on /usr/share/maven2/, then you can copy to your home folder as  jens mentioned

> $ cp /usr/share/maven3/conf/settings.xml   ~/.m2/settings.xml

Answer (score 39):

You can find your maven files here:

```
cd ~/.m2
```

Probably you need to [copy settings.xml](https://cwiki.apache.org/WICKET//setup-maven.html#SetupMaven-Configuration) in your `.m2` folder:

```
cp /usr/local/bin/apache-maven-2.2.1/conf/settings.xml .m2/
```

If no .m2 folder exists:

```
mkdir -p ~/.m2
```

Answer (score 13):

.m2 directory on linux box usually would be `$HOME/.m2`

you could get the $HOME :

```
echo $HOME
```

or simply:

```
cd <enter>
```

to go to your home directory.

other information from maven site:
http://maven.apache.org/download.html#Installation

Comment: I couldn't find .m2 in home directory

Comment: good suggestion will have a try :)

Comment: If you run something like `mvn clean` on the command line it normally creates this folder for you. At least it does on windows anyway.

Comment: Was trying it out in a new system so it was not present after doing a fresh `mvn clean` it got created. Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

Quoted from http://maven.apache.org/settings.html:

> There are two locations where a settings.xml file may live:
>
> The Maven install: $M2_HOME/conf/settings.xml
>
> A user's install: ${user.home}/.m2/settings.xml

So, usually for a specific user you edit

```
/home/*username*/.m2/settings.xml
```

To set environment for all local users, you might think about changing the first path.