# Alternative to maven codehaus

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-dependency-plugin

My maven project uses codehaus [ https://www.codehaus.org/termination/ ] repositories. But these services are terminated and they suggested to do something for the alternative ( Alternate artifacts or mirrors ).

As I am new to maven i couldn't figure out how to employee those alternatives.
For reference use https://www.codehaus.org/mechanics/maven/

thing is i cant find .m2 folder

Comment: .m2 folder will be by default ${user.home}/.m2 check this location

Comment: Which codehaus repository have you used?

Comment: mojo, janino, jackson

Comment: Possible duplicate of [.m2 , settings.xml in Ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358635/m2-settings-xml-in-ubuntu)

Comment: You should simply use Maven Central...

Comment: I did not find it under user.home

Comment: What did you not found under user.home ?