# How to update the version of Maven used by IntellijIdea

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I try to open the Maven project in IntellijIdea. This project uses spark and scala. When I run:

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

then it gives the error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.scalastyle:scalastyle-maven-plugin:0.7.0:check (default) on
>   project spark-mllib_2.10: Failed during scalastyle execution: You have
>   50 Scalastyle violation(s)

I think that the problem is in the version of Maven. Indeed in IntellijIdea Settings I have the version Bundled (Maven 3) 3.0.5, while pom.xml defines `<maven.version>3.3.3</maven.version>`
If I run `mvn -version` in terminal, it points Maven 3.3.3

So, how can I update the version of Maven used by IntellijIdea?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

1. Install the new version of maven (If not already installed)
2. Go to File -> Settings and use the search bar to find maven settings
3. Edit the `Maven home directory` setting so it points to the installation folder of the desired version

Comment: The problem is that `which maven` indicates `/usr/bin/mvn`. But when I try to set this folder by clicking on `...` next to `Maven home directory`, only one folder appears inside `/usr/bin/` (this is a correct `/usr/`) and `mvn` does not appear there.

Comment: @Klue If you installed it using a package manager like apt-get, [this SO answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5312458/5902532) might help you locate your maven installation

Answer (score 1):

It may sometimes happen that after configuring maven in Intellij and changing as following it does not work by command build, so build it by Intellij maven tool.

Setting > Maven > Importer - select the `JDK`
Setting > Maven > Runner - select the `JRE`
After that, try to build by Intellij maven tool instead of Intellij console.

Answer (score 0):

To change bundled maven in IntelliJ

Close the IntelliJ IDE
go to installed directory of IntelliJ
then navigate to \plugins\maven\lib

replace existing maven3 folder with your maven version.
make sure you have renamed the maven directory correctly (maven3)
start the IDE and check the version.