# How to update Maven plugin version in Intellij

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I need to update the Maven plugin used by Intellij.

I found this question which is basically the same, but it didn't help me solve my problem [How to update the version of Maven used by IntellijIdea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36603481/how-to-update-the-version-of-maven-used-by-intellijidea) because it says "Edit the Maven home directory setting" but I don't see this in settings (screenshot below).

The situation is this: I've installed the [newest version of Maven](https://maven.apache.org/docs/history.html) (3.9.4), but when I go to Intellij settings, the version used is still 3.8.1, and I would like to update this. Here are my screenshots.

[image: screenshot of Maven version installed]

[image: screenshot of Which Maven version Intellij is still using]

In the Maven settings in Intellij, do I have to tick the option "Override" in "Local repository" and copy-paste the new path? Or copy-paste it in "Maven home path"?

Comment: I don't use IntelliJ but it looks to me like you should be able to browse to your new Maven home

Comment: If you version in IntelliJ is shows 3.8.1 that means your IDE it not up-to-date... Upgrade to most recent version of IntelliJ...

Answer (score 1):

From the main menu select `File | Settings | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven`

On the **Maven** settings page, in the **Maven home path** field, specify the location of the Maven custom version installation.

For the Maven wrapper, select the **use Maven wrapper** option from the list. In this case the version of Maven defined in the **.mvn/wrapper/maven-wrapper.properties** file will be used.

[image]